# How to define a function in typescript that returns string or an object?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns string, or an object.

For example:

`myFunc(path: string): string | object`

If I know the specific shape of the object I am expecting, how can I use this function so it matches `MyObjectProps` type instead of `object`?

ie.

```
type MyObjectProps = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

Comment: How would you define a function that returns `MyObjectProps`?

Comment: I have to do `myFunc('asdf') as MyObjectProps` right?

Comment: Well, logically, if you write `myFunc(path: string): string` to define a function that takes a path (which is a string) and returns a string, how would you alter that line of code so that it defined a function that takes a path (which is a string) and returns a `MyObjectProps`?

Comment: Easiest way might be a typeguard, assertion function or just cast it to the thing you *know* it is using the `as` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy! Just get rid of the 'object' and replace with 'MyObjectProps'

```
myFunc(path: string): string | MyObjectProps
```

Note that it's considered good practice to use an interface instead of a type where possible:

```
interface MyObjectProps {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```